# Hibernate exception while upgrade the version to 5.4.31.Final

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a web application where I have been used

```
org.springframework-version: 4.1.4.RELEASE
spring.security.version: 3.2.5.RELEASE
org.hibernate-version: 3.5.1-Final.
```

I'm trying to upgrade the **spring**, and the **hibernate** version where I successfully updated the following in my pom file

```
org.springframework-version: 5.3.6
spring.security.version: 5.4.6
org.hibernate-version: 5.4.31.Final
```

And I have also updated the related XML file where I mentioned the spring security beans. I'm using Postgres DB. Now I'm facing the following issue.

> WARN o.h.e.j.c.i.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService - HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
> 20210507-18:39:17.093 sitepm-web [main] WARN o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections

> ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext - Context initialization failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]

beans in my root-context.xml file

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
    <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
    </bean>
```